# SharePoint site prompt username and password

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, credentials

Everything is working fine but I have a strange behavior.

When I leave my office and came after 1 hour , the site is asking to enter user name and password.

In the same browser, and the same session, when I open a new tab, add the same url, it's working without prompt. The URL is of trusted site.

I am sure it's not a permissions issue.

Is there a session timeout or something like this?

## edit1

Issue happened in Chrome and IE is set to login with the current user and password!

## edit2

I didn't submit information in form! I just locked my PC and came back after 30 minutes approximately, perform refresh, the chrome asking for user name and password for all sites!

Comment: Windows or form based authentication?

Comment: Windows authentication

Comment: Try to use Fiddler on your client to perform further troubleshooting.

Comment: Nothing shows in fiddler

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use IE browser?

If that’s the case, go to Tools->Internet options->Security tab->Local intranet->Custom level->scroll down to user authentication section, select “Automatic logon with current user name and password” and check again.

Comment: We have a global policy and the url added to the trusted site and this setting already done for all users! I got this issue in IE and chrome,  any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is session time out in SharePoint. By default, SharePoint has a 10-hour session timeout. But, your admins can change it through Central Administration settings or using powershell.

**Using Central Admin:**
Open Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage web application -> Select Your web application -> Click on General Settings -> Here in web page security validation section you can set the session time out period as shown below : 
[image]

Using Powershell:
You can find the script [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-change-the-session-566ba208).

Comment: Thank you, what's the security validation means in this context?

Comment: Its the timeout for that particular user on the SharePoint site. After this expiry time, the user needs to either refresh the page or enter credentials again. If the above doesn't help, you can check this - https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/888828/the-security-validation-for-this-page-has-timed-out-error-message-when

Comment: I didn't submit information in form! I just locked my PC and come back after 30 minutes, perform refresh, the browser ask for user name and password

Comment: Some SharePoint timeout is 30minutes by default. Can you check it in central administration?